# не работает связка window.location, window.scrollBy

Tags: javascript

Проверял в 3-х браузерах Chrome, iOS - не работает. IE - работает (сюрприз)

```js
window.location='#flash', window.scrollBy(0, -250);​
```

Если по отдельности использовать, то пашет. Вместе - нет(

[Вот сайт, шарик Flashmob должен иметь отступ в 250px от верха](https://sortavala.city-guides.ru/now/index.htm?spot=1#flash)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51301/discussion-on-question-by-----window-location-window-scr).